# Facebook desktop app submission error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

We have a Windows desktop app (Java based) that enables the user to publish statistics on his Facebook profile.

Implementation is working well, using the custom flow (in-app web browser to ask Facebook authorization: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URL&response_type=token&scope=publish_actions).

This works perfectly in the sandbox/test environment provided by Facebook.

Problem is that now we want to submit our application for review by Facebook so that it can work in real environment (ie. not limited to test) but unfortunately it indicates an error when submitting:

> "It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content
>   with the publish_actions permission in the last 30 days."

[image: Screenshot]

As we already made access using publish_actions permission in Facebook's test environment, we're not sure what is missing. Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: You need to publish something using the permission with the admin user of the app.